# Fdisk does not match /proc/partitions or mount points (embedded)

Tags: linux, partition, embedded, fdisk, busybox

I'm working on an existing embedded Linux device and am having trouble editing the partitions using fdisk. My goal is to create a partition for testing purposes on **/dev/sda**. I am using the fdisk bundled with BusyBox v1.23.2. Please see below for my conundrum:

```
# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name
8        0   56582144 sda
8        1          8 sda1
8        2      32768 sda2
8        3     262144 sda3
8        4       1024 sda4
8        5        512 sda5
8        6        512 sda6
8        7   56285132 sda7
```

Notice that there are 7 partitions listed for **sda**

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sda: 57.9 GB, 57940115456 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 877 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16128 * 4096 = 66060288 bytes

  Device Boot        Start        End       Blocks    Id    System
/dev/sda1                1     266306   4294967292    ee    EFI GPT
Partition 1 has different physical/logical beginnings (non-Linux?):
        phys=(0,0,1) logical=(0,0,2)
Partition 1 has different physical/logical endings:
        phys=(1023, 255, 63) logical=(266305, 4, 4)
```

No information is shown regarding the remaining 6 partitions **sda2 - sda7**.

Let's look at what is actually mounted right now

```
# mount | grep '^/dev'
/dev/root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata on /data type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered)
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modem on /firmware type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/dsp on /dsp type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered)
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/bluetooth on /bt_firmware type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

Pay special attention to `/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata` being mounted on `/data` here. Let's check what partition **userdata** refers to:

```
# ls -alh /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name | grep userdata
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           9 Jan 12 20:34 userdata -> /dev/sda7
```

We can see here that `/dev/sda7` is being used, as it is mounted at `/data`. Is there anything I might be able to do so that fdisk properly recognizes all the partitions and allows me to edit them?

Comment: `sfdisk -l /dev/sda`?

Comment: I do not have access to sfdisk or cfdisk atm. I will attempt to add sfdisk to busybox, reflash, and get back to you with that info

Comment: alternatively, `lsblk`?

Comment: lsblk is also not already in BusyBox. I'll have to see if that is available as well. I don't see any option to add sfdisk in the menuconfig :(

Comment: maybe you can dd partition table to file, move to other machine, and there use sfdisk or fdisk?

Comment: @KrzysztofStasiak that's a great suggestion, I will try to analyze that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) (GPT) on `/dev/sda`, and `fdisk`, especially early versions or small embedded versions don't work with GPTs. What you see is a sort of "compatibility" output that doesn't show you the real structure, and you won't be able to change partition data with `fdisk`.

Options:

(1) Take out harddisk, connect it to some other computer, use `gparted` etc. to manipulate GPT partition table.

(2) Look through the binaries (non-busybox) on your embedded device to see if you have something that can modify GPTs, e.g. `gdisk`/`cgdisk`/`sgdisk`.

(3) Cross-compile `gdisk`/`cgdisk`/`sgdisk` or a similar program, or maybe even `gparted`, so it works on your embedded device.

(4) Put in old-style MBR partition table on the harddisk instead of the GPT, and try to keep the partitions you want to keep (if you want to make a new partition, at least one of the old partitions has to go, anyway). This can destroy data if you are not careful, so make a backup first.

Comment: It looks like I'll have to go with option 3. I was not aware that fdisk did not have GPT support. Thanks so much for the valuable info!